# Is it possible to get deb packages of older VLC versions?

Tags: vlc, deb, versions

I need to use v. 2.0.8 for a VLC extension that does not work with the latest releases of the player. I would like to keep the deb of this version for further use, and also to learn how is it  possible in general to get the deb files of older versions.

I found that the deb for 2.1.1 version can be downloaded from [here](http://packages.debian.org/sid/i386/vlc/download) - but where from the older ones?

Comment: You can get v 2.0.6 off of [Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/vlc/?source=directory). 2.0.8 can be [got off of the Vlc website](http://download.videolan.org/pub/videolan/vlc/2.0.8/). For both you may need to `make` `configure` `install` to install them.

Comment: @wilf - that is why i was asking about a deb - the `make` command makes me feel like the newbie i am

Comment: Found [this](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-security/+archive/ppa/+build/4844533) - would this work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some 2.0.x. versions - including 2.0.8: [here](http://pkgs.org/download/vlc).

Click [here](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/v/vlc/vlc_2.0.8-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_i386.deb) to download v.2.0.8 i386.

Comment: You mean http://pkgs.org/ubuntu-13.10/ubuntu-universe-i386/vlc_2.0.8-1_i386.deb.html - for 13.10 atleast.

Comment: I wish this worked on Ubuntu 20. I hate it when shared libraries aren't included.